# I have a JSON column called authorsjson which has json data. I want to find all the users whose names start with a given string

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I have a hybrid database in which there are both normal columns and columns with json data in them. I have this data in authorsjson column

```
{
                "profileUrl": "https://disqus.com/by/mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2/",
                "isPrivate": false,
                "isPrimary": true,
                "about": "",
                "username": "mnaid-233509073ed3432027d48b1a83f5fbd2",
                "url": "",
                "id": "250728493",
                "isAnonymous": false,
                "location": "",
                "isPowerContributor": false,
                "signedUrl": "",
                "joinedAt": "2017-05-03T10:40:52",
                "disable3rdPartyTrackers": true,
                "name": "baggiebuoy"
            }
```

"The goal is to find all users whose names start with a given string."

The following is my attempt at the sql query:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(authorsjson, '$.name') 
FROM altthree 
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(authorsjson, '$.name') like 'b%' ;
```

I am getting a single column which is empty.
Anybody knows how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the double-quotes before your search string, OR better still, to use JSON_UNQUOTE:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(authorsjson, '$.name')
FROM altthree 
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(authorsjson, '$.name')) like 'b%' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems almost ok, it's just the field 'name' is nested one level deeper, try modiying the third line like this:

```
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(authorsjson, '$.author.name') like 'b%' ;
```

Comment: I just edited my json column value....theres no mention of author in the column...

Comment: its not actually nested in the column, I just put it up there so that it is clear...